# how to create an executable file in electron

Tags: electron

I created a simple project with electron and I tried to create an executable file.

system: Ubuntu 18.0.4.

I added this script to my package.json:
    "build":"electron-packager . MyApp"
and after I run it I got a new folder named "MyApp"

[folder hirarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnxet.png)

[image]

I nevigated to MyApp/resources/app
and I did not manage to find there an executable file.

the only files that I can see is .asar file

what should be the file extention anyway?

and what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the executable with [Electron Builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder). Please read the Quick Setup Guide through and follow the instructions. After that you should have app running. It is really quite straight forward and seems to work well on Windows and Mac.